# grails 3 - Specified config option does not exist for class - error

Tags: grails

I have a domain class where I specify the order of fields in the constraints closure:

```
package com.myapp

class User {
    String loginId
    String password
    Date dateCreated

    static hasOne = [profile:Profile]
    static hasMany = [posts:Post, tags:Tag, following:User]

    static constraints = {
        loginId size: 3..20, unique: true
        password size: 6..8, validator: { passwd, user ->
            passwd != user.loginId
        }
        tags()
        posts()
        following()
        profile nullable: true
    }
}
```

I want *tags*, *posts* and following to appear in this order. However, I get 3 errors:

```
ERROR org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder - ORM Mapping Invalid: Specified config option [tags] does not exist for class [com.myapp.User]!
ERROR org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder - ORM Mapping Invalid: Specified config option [posts] does not exist for class [com.myapp.User]!
ERROR org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder - ORM Mapping Invalid: Specified config option [following] does not exist for class [com.myapp.User]!
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: try removing them from your constraints. They aren't needed there. `tags()`, `posts()`, `following()`

Comment: I would replace the `tags()` with `tags nullable: false`.

Comment: You want tags, posts, and following to appear where in that order? 

Just trying to understand the use case. If its in a user interface, that's the business of the view, not the model.